# What was the military age in Romania between the world wars?

Tags: military, romania, conscription

In order to understand some facts in my family’s history I am trying to figure out what was the military age in Romania between the world wars.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Answer (score 4):

On a website that is promoted as a representative of the Romanian defense ministry I have found [an article on the history of military service in Romania](http://presamil.ro/scurta-privire-istorica-asupra-serviciului-militar-obligatoriu/):

> On June 23, 1924, a new law on the organization of the army was adopted, according to which the country's armed forces were composed of the active army with permanent cadres, its reserve and militias.

> Military service lasted two or three years (three years for the navy, air force, border guards and gendarmes), it was mandatory for all male healthy citizens, *starting at the age of 21*, regardless of nationality.

> During campaign, active soldiers and reservists *up to the age of 29* constituted the operative part of the army, and the militia, made up of men between 41 and 50 years of age, was to frame the auxiliary structures of the army.
> ...

> "The law for the recruitment of the army", promulgated on July 4, 1930, whose provisions remained, in general terms, valid also in the second interwar decade, established the duration of military obligations at 29 years, from the age of 21 to 50, being divided as follows: active military training - two years (three for the navy, border guards and gendarmes); completion – three years (two years for weapons in which three years of activity were carried out); the reserve - 15 years and the militias - nine years.

(mostly Google translation)

The short answer would be:

- active training 21-23, or 21-24 years old
- reserves - up to 50 years old

(The article is signed by Colonel Florin Sperlea,
PhD in History, further details at link)